# Just the data output doesn't work in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
import styles from './PopularPosts.module.scss'

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    return {
        props: {
            content: "Some content"
        }
    }
}

export const PopularPosts = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>{props.content}</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

I want to output simple data from an object in a project on Next.js, but it returns an empty h1 title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use getServerSideProps in components. If you use `PopularPosts` as page, you should export `PopularPosts` as default.

```
import styles from './PopularPosts.module.scss'

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    return {
        props: {
            content: "Some content"
        }
    }
}

const PopularPosts = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>{props.content}</h1>
        </>
    )
}
export default PopularPosts
```